# Why do we need to find 5 Higgs Bosons to prove the existence of the dark matter?

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry, dark-matter, higgs

I was recently watching a show that say we need at least 5 Higgs Boson to prove the existence of the dark matter because it will strengthen the concept of symmetry.

Why is that so? Because, I am not getting what it says.

Comment: Neuneck is saying the right thing, as is confirmed by all those upvotes... Three parts of the Higgs field become part of W+,W-,Z bosons. In the standard model, the Higgs field has 4 parts so one part is left over and that is "the" Higgs boson. In the supersymmetric standard model, there are two 4-part Higgs fields, so eight parts, so there are five different Higgs bosons left over after Ws and Z get their masses.

Comment: Some of the other new particles in the supersymmetric standard model could be the dark matter. But the dark matter could also be something quite different, like right-handed neutrinos. So the reality is more the reverse of what you said or what you heard: *if* the dark matter is explained by supersymmetry, *then* there should be 4 more Higgs bosons out there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The show you watched seems to get two concepts mixed up: Supersymmetry and Dark Matter.

The existence of Dark Matter is [strongly hinted at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Observational_evidence) by comsological and astrophysical considerations. It is the easiest explanation for several observations we make in the universe.

[Supersymmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) on the other hand provides a candidate particle. The lightest supersymmetric particle is conjectured to be stable and could therefore constitute Dark Matter. Also, supersymmetry has (at least) 5 Higgs bosons, which is most surely the context in which that number came up in the show.

So, while the (direct) observation of Dark Matter and additional Higgs bosons at the LHC would make a strong case for supersymmetry, both concepts are primarily unrelated.